# JSON.parse кидает ошибку unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON

Tags: ajax, javascript, json_encode, json, php

Есть код аякс

```
$.ajax({                                            url: './',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                data: {comment_author: comment_author, comment_text: comment_text, parrent: parrent, film_id: film_id},
                                                success: function(res){
                                                    var result = JSON.parse(res);
                                                    console.log(result);
                                                },
                                                error: function(){
                                                    alert("Ошибка!");
                                                }
                                            });
```

Есть функция в модели, которая возвращает в контроллере строку JSON

```
function add_comment(){
    global $dbh;
    $comment_author = $_POST['comment_author'];
    $comment_text = $_POST['comment_text'];
    $parent = (int) $_POST['parrent'];
    $film_id = (int) $_POST['film_id'];
    if(!$film_id){
        $res = array('result' => 'Неизвестный фильм');
        return json_encode($res);
    }
    if(empty($comment_author) OR empty($comment_text)){
        $res = array('result' => 'Не заполнены поля');
        return json_encode($res);
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO comments (comment_author, comment_text, parent_id, comment_film_id) VALUES('$comment_author', '$comment_text', $parent, $film_id)";
    $res = $dbh->query($query);
    $count = $res->rowCount();
    if($count){
        $res = array('result' => 'Все ок');
        echo json_encode($res);
    }else{
        $res = array('result' => 'Ошибка');
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
}
```

Но консоль выдает ошибку

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 106 of the JSON data
```

Не могу найти проблему

Comment: @KoRNeT46RuS, посмотрите ответ в консоли. Судя по вашему коду, что-то мне подсказывает, что кроме json-строки, вы там увидите еще что-нибудь: например, ошибку. Кстати, **dataType: 'json'** избавляет от **JSON.parse()**. И еще (*не по теме*) - а зачем использовать PDO и не пользоваться плейсхолдерами, тем более, что судя по запросу, вы добавляете данные, которые вносить может кто-угодно.

Comment: Определитесь с тем как возвращаете ответ, либо echo либо return